# How to implement a "main" block in ANTLR4 grammar?

Tags: antlr4, grammar, program-entry-point

I would like to implement a "main" block in my programming language created with ANTLR4. So, that there could only be one function named "main" and that it would be required to run the code. Also, only the functions called from the "main" block should work.

```
grammar TL;

parse
 : block EOF
 ;

block
 : ( statement | functionDecl )* ( Return expression )?
 ;

statement
 : assignment
 | functionCall
 | ifStatement
 | forStatement
 | whileStatement
 ;

assignment
 :  Identifier indexes?'=' expression
 ;

functionCall
 : Identifier '(' exprList? ')' #identifierFunctionCall
 | Spausdink '(' expression? ')'  #printlnFunctionCall
 | Convert '(' expression ',' expression ',' expression ')' #convertFunctionCall
 ;

ifStatement
 : ifas elseIfStat* elseStat? '}'
 ;

ifas
 : If '(' expression ')' '{' block
 ;

elseIfStat
 : Else If '(' expression ')' '{' block
 ;

elseStat
 : Else '{' block
 ;

functionDecl
 : View Function Identifier '(' idList? ')' '{' block '}'
 ;

forStatement
 : Floop '(' Identifier '=' expression ',' expression ',' expression ')' '{' block '}'
 ;

whileStatement
 : Wloop '(' expression ')' '{' block '}'
 ;

idList
 : Identifier ( ',' Identifier )*
 ;

exprList
 : expression ( ',' expression )*
 ;

expression
 : '-' expression                                       #unaryMinusExpression
 | '!' expression                                       #notExpression
 | <assoc=right> expression '^' expression              #powerExpression
 | expression op=( '*' | '/' | '%' ) expression         #multExpression
 | expression op=( '+' | '-' ) expression               #addExpression
 | expression op=( '>=' | '<=' | '>' | '<' ) expression #compExpression
 | expression op=( '==' | '!=' ) expression             #eqExpression
 | expression '&&' expression                           #andExpression
 | expression '||' expression                           #orExpression
 | expression '?' expression ':' expression             #ternaryExpression
 | Number                                               #numberExpression
 | Bool                                                 #boolExpression
 | Null                                                 #nullExpression
 | functionCall indexes?                                #functionCallExpression
 | list indexes?                                        #listExpression
 | Identifier indexes?                                  #identifierExpression
 | String indexes?                                      #stringExpression
 | '(' expression ')' indexes?                          #expressionExpression
 | Input '(' String? ')'                                #inputExpression
 ;

list
 : '[' exprList? ']'
 ;

indexes
 : ( '[' expression ']' )+
 ;

Spausdink  : 'spausdink';
Convert    : 'convert';
For        : 'for';
While      : 'while';
Input      : 'input';
View       : 'view';
If         : 'if';
Else       : 'else';
Return     : 'return';
Floop      : 'floop';
Wloop      : 'wloop';
Null       : 'null';
Function   : 'function';

Or       : '||';
And      : '&&';
Equals   : '==';
NEquals  : '!=';
GTEquals : '>=';
LTEquals : '<=';
Pow      : '^';
Excl     : '!';
GT       : '>';
LT       : '<';
Add      : '+';
Subtract : '-';
Multiply : '*';
Divide   : '/';
Modulus  : '%';
OBrace   : '{';
CBrace   : '}';
OBracket : '[';
CBracket : ']';
OParen   : '(';
CParen   : ')';
SColon   : ';';
Assign   : '=';
Comma    : ',';
QMark    : '?';
Colon    : ':';

Bool
 : 'true'
 | 'false'
 ;

Number
 : Int ( '.' Digit* )?
 ;

Identifier
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

String
 : ["] ( ~["\r\n\\] | '\\' ~[\r\n] )* ["]
 | ['] ( ~['\r\n\\] | '\\' ~[\r\n] )* [']
 ;

Comment
 : ( '//' ~[\r\n]* | '/*' .*? '*/' ) -> skip
 ;

Space
 : [ \t\r\n\u000C] -> skip
 ;

fragment Int
 : [1-9] Digit*
 | '0'
 ;

fragment Digit
 : [0-9]
 ;
```

In addition, if there's code that's not a function outside the "main" block, should give an error.

I would like the input code to look like this :

```
view function count (value) {
      return value * 10
}

view function main() {
      value = 1
      value = count(value) // calling function
      spausdink(value) // printing the value
      return 0
}
```

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

TLDR :
How to add restrictions to code grammar, so that the functions could only be called from the "main" function, there has to be a "main" function to run the code, otherwise an error should appear. And the code can't have two "main" functions.

Comment: OK, and what is going wrong?

Comment: I don't know how to add the restrictions for the input code. So that the functions could only be called from the "main" function and that the "main" function is required to run the code, otherwise it should give an error.

Comment: Then I recommend you throw away that grammar you found on Github, and start with a more basic ANTLR4 tutorial. You're trying to  run before being able to walk. I've heard good things about this one: https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/ . Good luck!

Comment: You can't encode that kind of restriction in the grammar. Just parse the code normally and then check the reachability of functions afterwards as a separate phase.

Comment: Well, you could define a `mainBlock` that has a `functionCall` alternative, which can then be removed from the `block` rule. But checking afterwards is the way to go.